# git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?

Tags: git, clone

So I created a remote repo that's *not* bare (because I need redmine to be able to read it),
and it's set to be shared with the group (so git init --shared=group).  I was able to push to the remote repo and now I'm trying to clone it.

If I clone it over the net I get this:

```
remote: Counting objects: 4648, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2837/2837), done.
error: git-upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.B/s  
fatal: git-upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I'm able to clone it locally without a problem, and I ran "git fsck", which only reports some dangling trees/blobs, which I understand aren't a problem.  What could be causing this?  I'm still able to pull from it, just not clone.  I should note the remote git version is 1.5.6.5 while local is 1.6.0.4

I tried cloning my local copy of the repo, stripping out the .git folder and pushing to a new repo, then cloning the new repo and I get the same error, which leads me to believe it may be a file in the repo that's causing git-upload-pack to fail...

Edit:
I have a number of windows binaries in the repo, because I just built the python modules and then stuck them in there so everyone else didn't have to build them as well.  If I remove the windows binaries and push to a new repo, I can clone again, perhaps that gives a clue.  Trying to narrow down exactly what file is causing the problem now.

Comment: it seems to be a bug with cygwin, if you retry it might work.

Comment: just FYI, cloning locally just do hardlinks, so it may not do `index-pack` or check for error.

Comment: yep, retry and it might work... it seems to fail less over https for some reason in my case

Comment: I've got **exact same error messages**. Except it also brings dozens of the following, all repeated, `error: packfile .git/objects/pack/pack-5f2b4b46e2dba195a0fa5d29dfd3cef88067f8ed.pack does not match index` and `warning:` + same 'pack' msg + `cannot be accessed`. It only happens when trying to clone from this one specific machine. Or, after it fails, when trying to pull it happens as well. Later it seems we can continue trying until it eventually finishes up. Any other machine cloning from that repo have no issues at all. The win server is bare and all machines are windows with cygwin.

Comment: If you have more than one *physical* drive on your computer, try the clone on a different drive.

Comment: On Windows 10, if you use AVG anti virus, try to disable AVG. (tested with avg Feb/2019 and git for windows 2.20.0)

Answer (score 21):

The way I solved this problem is this: My git daemon is running on windows, and clients are on other computers.

I found a workaround (but it will only work on windows).

Start git daemon with verbose from cmd.exe:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c 'git.exe daemon --verbose  '
```

Not tested, if it works directly in git bash. Maybe it will.

Then (before starting any clone, pull, fetch,...) select some text in the window (note: "Quick Edit Mode" must be enabled (can be found in: cmd.exe --> Properties (click the top left corner of your cmd window) --> Edit Options)) in which git daemon runs. That will prevent it from printing any further messages in that window.

When the output thread of git daemon is blocked that way, then the error does not happen

Comment: Bizarre but this worked for me also. 
1. ran git bash on windows
2. started a daemon (git daemon --verbose --export-all --reuseaddr --base-path=.)
3. marked some text (system menu->edit->mark in the bash shell)
4. leave the text marked (don't press enter) and the daemon works fine (!),
otherwise early EOF error on the client every time.

Comment: Alternative for recent version of git involved 1. right-click 2. options window (leave it open while pulling..... :( )

Comment: Can't believe it... That made it work, but I must use the windows cmd, instead fo Git-bash. Mine doesn't have the `edit` menu @codeSF said. And leaving the options window open as @goofballLogic said didn't work either (windows 10)

Comment: This worked for me on windows 10 within the standard command shell (cmd.exe). Just clicked the window icon, Edit->Mark and selected some text. Very weird.

Comment: Has anyone run across an explanation of this behavior?  This is definitely a bug of some sort.  Is it somehow related to the "unable to set SO_KEEPALIVE" error message that gets printed?

Comment: Seems this was never solved. and even F5 and Network were unable to determine the cause. It happens only on 1 VPN profile .

Answer (score 14):

I have the same problem as you; the error message when I clone i:

```
Cloning into test...
remote: Counting objects: 6503, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4519/4519), done.
Connection to git.myhost.im closed by remote host.| 350 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

In my case, the reason is that my repository size (200M) is larger than my `git` server's memory (128M). When I clone from the `git` server, I use command `top` on my server, which shows that memory usage is soon over 128M.

When I use another server that has 4G memory, the `git clone` is all okay. You could also try adding more swap space to your sever.

Comment: Adding this to `.gitconfig` fixes: `[core]
    packedGitLimit = 512m
    packedGitWindowSize = 512m
[pack]
    deltaCacheSize = 2047m
    packSizeLimit = 2047m
    windowMemory = 2047m` - obviously line breaks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.
My guess also was that this has to do with the fact that I use text/CRLF mode for created files.
And indeed, after switching CygWin to UNIX/binary newline mode, everything works fine.

See:

- http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-textbinary.html
- http://www.sourceware.org/cygwin/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#mount

BTW, the easiest way for me to switch the file mode was to edit /etc/fstab
to switch from

> none /cygdrive cygdrive text,posix=0,user 0 0

to

> none /cygdrive cygdrive binary,posix=0,user 0 0

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue, cloning a github repository from github.com, running git 2.13 on SLES 12 SP3. Tried upgrading git to latest (v2.21 at the time), but that did not resolve the issue. Tried setting git config options suggested, and many other options, with no luck.

Ultimately, I did it by hand.

- created the directory manually.. `mkdir somedir`
- Ran `git init` to set up the directory for GIT.
- Manually added the github repo as an origin `git remote add origin http://github.com/git/git`
- Ran `git fetch` to grab the pack. This task failed with an error, but left behind the fetched-but-bad pack in `.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX`
- used `cat .git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX | git unpack-objects -r` to extract all the valid objects.
- Ran `git fetch` again to get anything (like branches and tags) missed from the prior attempts. No pack/objects needed because they were all unpacked.
- Finally, `git checkout master`, to get `HEAD` pointing at something real.

I'm not sure it was required for me, but I'd recommend `git fsck` and `git gc` after that, which will also trigger git to recreate the packs/indexes.

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems with cygwin git, the error: `fatal: index-pack failed`,

I was able to solve it by creating a mount for my projects and setting it to binary mode.  since my `/c` is set to text mode.

Add cygwin's to `/etc/fstab`:

```
c:/work/Projects /projects some_fs binary 0 0
```

run `mount -a` to mount all drives.

You need to be in `/projects` to work with cygwin `git`, `/c/work/Projects` will fail.

Not sure if this will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GIT_TRACE` environment variable to get debug output. Set it to "1" to trace to stderr or an absolute path to trace to file.

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem and I would change my git configs to and that is worked fine:

> git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 50m
>   git config --global pack.windowMemory 50m
>   git config --global core.compression 9

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Windows Defender was blocking access to the files by git, because I had turned on Ransomware Protection's Controlled folder access.
Adding git [here (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUCPj.jpg) to allow access did the trick.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please describe your answer more so easily understand by another person

Answer (score 0):

The git-daemon issue seems to have been resolved in [v2.17.0](https://git-scm.com/download/) (verified with a non working v2.16.2.1).
I.e. workaround of selecting text in console to "lock output buffer" should no longer be required.

From https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.17.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.17.0.txt:

> - Assorted fixes to "git daemon".
>     (merge ed15e58efe jk/daemon-fixes later to maint).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem or close to it but did not see the solution to my case in any of these threads.

In my case the problem was the firewall. Cloning small repositories worked anyway, but bigger ones failed. So if nothing else helps, firewall settings is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

This error could mask these problems:

- not enough disk space
- not enough RAM

If the instance with git is low on RAM then you could try to add a swap temporary:

```
fallocate -l 2G /swap
chmod 600 /swap
mkswap /swap
swapon /swap
```

when done:

```
swapoff /swap
rm -f /swap
```

Answer (score -1):

I upgraded my client computer's git source to the same version that the server is running and that fixed this for me.