# GIT - getting 'early eof' error on clone

Tags: git

I have a error Early EOF's (Index-Pack Failed) when I try to clone a project from a repository git.

But when I do a `git-pull` or `git-push` from my localhost to the repository, I have no problems.
The error gives me the message that the repository is corrupt. It's weird.

What factors can cause such errors? Does the server, where is the repository, has low memory?

Comment: Can you include the exact error message that you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[git clone fails with “index-pack” failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed) will list the most common causes for this error.

But note the current Cygwin version (if that is what you are using) has an [issue with git when cloning over ssh](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.cygwin/130843).

Depending on the server executing the git clone request, you also have issue when [cloning over ssh via git protocol](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Unable-to-clone-via-git-protocol-early-EOF-index-pack-failed-td6203553.html).

Comment: @Xinthral Cygwin? On Windows, [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) means you don't really need a separate Cygwin installation, [since it uses msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309). For a full Linux environment, WSL2 is also a good alternative.