# Heroku git pull error on mac

Tags: macos, git, heroku, eof

I have a Heroku project that has worked for months with no issues relating to git cloning, pushing, or pulling.  Recently, I started getting this error when performing a git pull:

```
remote: Counting objects: 729, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (308/308), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyKiB | 76 KiB/s   
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

There has been no significant changes to the code base.  I am well under the storage limit on Heroku.   A coworker of mine also cannot do a git clone of the heroku repository.  It results in the same error.  I have noticed that the early EOF line sometimes also includes this:

```
fatal: early EOFs:  24% (153/637), 196.00 KiB | 117 KiB/s
```

I am on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion Macbook Air, with the native server being utilized, and no other deep customizations that would impact the system.

Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, are you using Cygwin by any chance?

Comment: There is a possible earlier duplicate of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589498/git-getting-early-eof-error-on-clone.

Comment: Side note: it sounds like you're git pulling from a Heroku app repo quite often?  That's not something one typically does.

Comment: I added the operating system details above.  The possible earlier duplicate mentioned above related to git cloning, which is a part of mine as well, but not all of it.  A key difference being I was able to clone this originally with no issues, until a couple days ago.  I would say I try to do a git pull a couple times a week when in active development on a project, which is not unusual with repository collaboration projects.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have heard several say that Heroku is not a reliable repository platform, so I am taking that to heart, and moved my repository on over to BitBucket.  That solved my problem.  From now on all other repositories I create will be hosted there, and still deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

1. "Edit local .git/config"
2. Add compression = 0 to the [core] section.

Other solution:

Run `git config --add core.compression -1` from the terminal.

Comment: What makes you think this is relation to compression?

Comment: Saw this error in another context and it turned out to be compression-related. As I said, it's a workaround that might help. But again, we still need to know more about the environment that this issue is occuring in.

Comment: It still compresses I notice, when performing a git pull command to the remote server.  Is the compression for that command dependent on the remote git config options?