# PyCharm on a Mac fails to clone a repository: remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, macos, pycharm

I'm having a lot of trouble cloning a repository on a Mac and I need some troubleshooting tips. When I try to do VCS -> Checkout from Version Control -> Git, then type in the information for my repository, and then click clone, a progress bar starts loading. It gets about halfway, and then I get the following error message:

```
Clone failed
RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
early EOF
index-pack failed
```

I've read some other issues that seemed similar, but everyone else was using different tools than me and the solutions didn't seem applicable (though I could be wrong). Any ideas for how to troubleshoot this?

Edit: Different from the possible duplicate. I can do a git clone from the command line just fine. It just doesn't work when I try it from PyCharm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed)

Comment: Some other answers also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589498/git-getting-early-eof-error-on-clone and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed

Comment: Does the same happen when you try to clone from command line using `git clone`?

Comment: I can do a git clone from the command line successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and it seems like it happens because of a timeout. Go to File > Settings > Version Control > GitHub. Increase the connection timeout value. I did 50,000ms, but I picked that value arbitrarily. Then retry, if it fails put it as high as you can go and try again. It worked for me.

Comment: thanks alot, this helped me, it also helped that I changed the network provider to a faster one.