# Git for windows: fatal: early EOF

Tags: windows, git

Yesterday I installed a new Git windows server 2.6.4 that was working fine with a Mac git client (git protocol)

Today I am struggling to get a 2nd client (Windows 7) to work.  In the process of trying to make it work I have upgraded both the Windows server and client to the recently released git 2.7.0

I have tried disabling compression...I have tried both wireless and wired networks (the Windows client and server are sitting on the same desk).  I have disabled AV on the client.  I have tried tweaking the memory settings as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed)

Here is the client output:

```
bash> git clone git://server.fqdn/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
remote: 08:56:10.972997 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'pack-objects' '--revs' '--thin' '--stdout' '--progress' '--delta-base-offset'
remote: Counting objects: 76, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (76/76), 8.31 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
fatal: read error: Invalid argument
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
bash>
```

Here is the server output:

```
bash> ./gitd.bat

D:\tools\gitd>set GIT_TRACE=1

D:\tools\gitd>D:\tools\Git\bin\git.exe daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --base-path=D:\git --export-all --enable=receive-pack
08:59:49.023778 git.c:561               trace: exec: 'git-daemon' '--reuseaddr' '--verbose' '--base-path=D:\git' '--export-all' '--enable=receive-pack'
08:59:49.023778 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'git-daemon' '--reuseaddr' '--verbose' '--base-path=D:\git' '--export-all' '--enable=receive-pack'
[7376] Ready to rumble
09:00:03.056268 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'D:\tools\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-daemon.exe' '--serve' '--reuseaddr' '--verbose' '--base-path=D:\git' '--export-all' '--enable=receive-pack'
[6492] Connection from 10...:54729
[6492] Extended attributes (27 bytes) exist 
[6492] Request upload-pack for '/repo.git'
09:00:03.087469 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'upload-pack' '--strict' '--timeout=0' '.'
[6492] 09:00:03.134269 git.c:561               trace: exec: 'git-upload-pack' '--strict' '--timeout=0' '.'
[6492] 09:00:03.134269 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'git-upload-pack' '--strict' '--timeout=0' '.'
[6492] 09:00:03.617872 run-command.c:343       trace: run_command: 'pack-objects' '--revs' '--thin' '--stdout' '--progress' '--delta-base-offset'
```

What else can I try?

Comment: I gave up and started using ssh protocol instead

Answer (score 8):

Git daemon is known to work on Windows **only when some text is selected
in git daemon's console window** (e.g., see
[git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed#)).
This text selection delays daemon's output, which somehow helps (!). As
soon as text selection is cleared (with Escape key), cloning/fetching
fails most of the time. Select text again, and cloning/fetching resumes
to work. The problem can be easily reproduced on Windows 10 using git
`2.11.0.windows.1` by cloning locally via
`git clone git://127.0.0.1/my-repo`.

Comment: OMG WTF! This fixed it for me. But how is this "known"?

Comment: @AyCe, this knowledge is documented in Martin's answer to the "git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?" question (see the link in my answer). I don't know how Martin managed to find that workaround. Also, this knowledge is documented in [git-for-windows issue #304: Investigate git daemon problems](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/304).

Answer (score 1):

I have found another solution, only start the `**git-daemon.exe directly**` e.g.

For the 64bit git: 

`"C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-daemon.exe"`


--> *with the same paramters as git.exe*. 

Then it works without the selection text.