# Git daemon clone fatal error in sideband demultiplexer and read error invalid argument

Tags: git, daemon, git-daemon

I'm trying to figure out git daemon.

I have seen many posts and threads including Stack Overflow questions regarding this issue, however none of the solutions helped me.

The repo is 100% not corrupted.

The thing is, I can easily clone the repo via 127.0.0.1, cloning on the same pc where daemon is running with my external IP works around once every 10 attempts, giving "`error in sideband demultiplexer`"

[image: screenshot]

Cloning from another PC in different network using my external IP gives the "`read error invalid argument, early EOFs, index-pack failed`"

[image: another screenshot]

What can be the reason to this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been reported before, since 2015: a clone from a Git for Windows daemon is flaky:

- [issue 139](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/139)
- [issue 304](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/304): a [patch was in progress](https://public-inbox.org/git/20180412210757.7792-1-kgybels@infogroep.be/), but was not included.

See if delaying the daemon execution through text selection in the console helps, [as reported here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779686/6309).

Comment: Selection does not change anything, neither in bash wrapper, nor in console. Still getting same errors.

Comment: @ymdred16 Is there a reason why you need the ssh daemon, as opposed to, for instance openssh? (which is in Windows 10: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview)

Comment: No particular reason actually. I am a complete newbie in git, so I wanted the most simplest way to share repos with my collaborator, and it seemed pretty easy to set up git daemon. I guess git daemon is not an option for me any more.

Comment: @ymdred16 no, it is a legacy mechanism, which is not used anymore. Other protocoles exist: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: Okay, seems like I misunderstood it. I am going to check the other options. Thanks :)