# Git Clone fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, git-clone

When I run `git clone` I get the following error:

```
git clone http://url/../project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: Counting objects: 1304, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (964/964), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly MiB | 9.62 MiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I have looked into fixing it and found a few solutions on stackoverflow, but none have seemed to work for me.

I have tried the solution from this [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21277806/fatal-early-eof-fatal-index-pack-failed), however It fails with the same error when I try to run `git fetch --unshallow` or `git fetch --depth=2147483647`

I have also tried increasing the postBuffer, as suggested in some other threads, with no success.

Comment: checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed

Comment: Where would I find the `.gitconfig` file in a windows install of git?

Comment: I located `.gitconfig` at `C:\\Users\\MyUser\\.gitconfig`. The suggestion made in the thread you linked to also does not work. I get the same error as above.