# Git clone a little bit at a time or other solutions

Tags: windows, git, tfs, clone, git-clone

I'm working on a Windows machine, from git bash.

We recently moved our project from a TFS server to a git repo on the same server. As far as I know, this was all done in one commit. I am remote.

When I run `git clone <url>` the clone will start, but at some seemingly arbitrary point (a different one every time), it will fail with:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Recv failure: Connection was reset
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I was thinking perhaps if there were a way to clone the repo a few files at a time, that would work. It seems unlikely that such a solution exists. I have tried increasing the `http.postBuffer` to 157286400, and I do not think switching to ssh is an option for us currently. A shallow clone is unhelpful, as there has only been one commit. These are the solutions I've seen elsewhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "As far as I know, this was all done in one commit" Do you mean they just took the current state of the code and checked it in in one big commit losing all history and context? If so, consider using [`git-tfs`](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to translate the entire history. Then you can have a clean break with TFS rather than having to keep it around to refer to old history. Your complete history will be in Git.

Comment: And do the answers here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943914/git-clone-fails-with-index-pack-failed

Comment: I'll check out git-tfs. As for the answers, they unfortunately do not.

Comment: How large are the files in your checkout? If it's more than a few hundred megs Git can have problems. You might want to look into [git-lfs](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs) to slim down what is stored in the Git history. I think using `git-tfs` and `git-lfs` will help solve and avoid a host of problems. Good luck.